# React Grid Game (useEffect issue)- key down event listener trigger preventing other useEffect from firing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a grid game using React. Currently it consists of a player represented by a green cell and a bot represented by an orange cell, paths and walls are grey and yellow respectively.

I'm am using an array of divs displayed in a grid. I am using objects to store the information of each cell an then manipulating those objects to make stuff happen.

I'm using useState to track the player and bot current positions.

A useEffect to trigger grid updates when the useState positional variables are changed.

A useEffect to add a key down event listener which governs player movements

A useEffect to randomly select a direction for the bot to move using a set interval.

The problem is that when I hold down a key to move the player, the player moves but the bot will not update until I have released the key. I've been trying for hours to change dependency lists and combine useEffects so both positions will update.

Please does anybody have any ideas what I might be doing wrong? or at least a point in the right direction?

Many thanks

Drew

Code Below:

```
      import React from "react";
      import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
      import MakeCell from "./MakeCell"; // Import the MakeCell component

      function BotTech() {
        // State variables to manage player and bot positions, grid cells, etc.
        const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        const start = MakeCell("path", 0, 0); // Create a start cell using MakeCell component
        const [positionMemory, setPositionMemory] = useState(start);
        const [botPosition, setBotPosition] = useState({ x: 5, y: 5 });
        const [botPositionMemory, setBotPositionMemory] = useState(start);
        const numRows = 40; // Number of rows in the grid
        const numCols = 40; // Number of columns in the grid

        // Styling for the grid and its container
        const gridStyles = {
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`,
          gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`,
          gap: "0px",
          border: "1px solid black",
        };

        const sectionStyle = {
          width: "100vw",
          height: "91vh",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        };

        // State to track if mouse button is pressed
        const [mousePressed, setMousePressed] = useState(false);

        // Add a global event listener for mouse up
        useEffect(() => {
          const handleGlobalMouseUp = () => {
            setMousePressed(false);
          };

          document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);

          return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);
          };
        }, []);

        // State to store the grid cells
        const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);

        // Generate the initial grid with walls and paths
        useEffect(() => {
          const blockSize = 2; // Size of the wall blocks
          const gapSize = 1; // Gap between wall blocks

          const newGrid = [];

          for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
              let cellType;
              if (
                row % (blockSize + gapSize) >= gapSize &&
                col % (blockSize + gapSize) >= gapSize &&
                row % (blockSize + gapSize) < gapSize + blockSize &&
                col % (blockSize + gapSize) < gapSize + blockSize &&
                Math.random() < 0.5
              ) {
                cellType = "wall"; // Create wall cells based on conditions
              } else {
                cellType = "path"; // Create path cells
              }

              newGrid.push(MakeCell(cellType, row, col)); // Create a cell using MakeCell component
            }
          }
          setGrid(newGrid); // Update the grid state
        }, [numRows, numCols]);

        // Function to update a cell in the grid
        const updateCellInGrid = (cellIndex, newCell) => {
          setGrid((prevGrid) => {
            const updatedGrid = [...prevGrid];
            updatedGrid[cellIndex] = newCell;
            return updatedGrid;
          });
        };

        // Update the grid cells when the player or bot positions change
        useEffect(() => {
          const cellIndex1 = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${position.x}-${position.y}`
          );

          const cellIndex2 = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${botPosition.x}-${botPosition.y}`
          );

          if (grid[cellIndex1] !== { x: `${position.x}`, y: `${position.y}` }) {
            const updatedCell1 = MakeCell("player", position.x, position.y);
            updateCellInGrid(cellIndex1, updatedCell1);
          }

          if (grid[cellIndex2] !== { x: `${botPosition.x}`, y: `${botPosition.y}` }) {
            const updatedCell2 = MakeCell("player", botPosition.x, botPosition.y);
            updateCellInGrid(cellIndex2, updatedCell2);
          }
        }, [position, botPosition]);

        // Calculate new position based on offsets and grid boundaries
        const calculateNewPosition = (xOffset, yOffset, memory) => {
          const newX = (memory.x + xOffset + numRows) % numRows;
          const newY = (memory.y + yOffset + numCols) % numCols;
          return { x: newX, y: newY };
        };

        // Update player's position and memory when moving
        const updatePositionAndMemory = (newPosition) => {
          const cellMemoryIndex = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${positionMemory.y}-${positionMemory.x}`
          );

          updateCellInGrid(cellMemoryIndex, positionMemory);

          const cellIndex = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${newPosition.x}-${newPosition.y}`
          );

          setPositionMemory(grid[cellIndex]);
          setPosition(newPosition);
        };

        // Update bot's position and memory when moving
        const updatePositionAndMemoryBot = (newPosition) => {
          const cellMemoryIndex = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${botPositionMemory.y}-${botPositionMemory.x}`
          );

          updateCellInGrid(cellMemoryIndex, botPositionMemory);

          const cellIndex = grid.findIndex(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${newPosition.x}-${newPosition.y}`
          );

          setBotPositionMemory(grid[cellIndex]);
          setBotPosition(newPosition);
        };

        // Function to move a cell based on offsets and update its position
        const move = (movementX, movementY, position, updateFunc) => {
          const newPosition = calculateNewPosition(movementX, movementY, position);
          const cell = grid.find(
            (cell) => cell.key === `${newPosition.x}-${newPosition.y}`
          );

          if (cell?.traverse) {
            updateFunc(newPosition);
          }
        };

        // Function to move the player cell
        const movePlayer = (
          movementX,
          movementY,
          position,
          updatePositionAndMemory
        ) => {
          move(movementX, movementY, position, updatePositionAndMemory);
        };

        // Function to move the bot cell
        const moveBot = (
          movementX,
          movementY,
          botPosition,
          updatePositionAndMemoryBot
        ) => {
          move(movementX, movementY, botPosition, updatePositionAndMemoryBot);
        };

        // Listen for key presses to move the player
        useEffect(() => {
          const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
            switch (event.key) {
              case "ArrowUp":
                movePlayer(-1, 0, position, updatePositionAndMemory);
                break;
              case "ArrowDown":
                movePlayer(1, 0, position, updatePositionAndMemory);
                break;
              case "ArrowLeft":
                movePlayer(0, -1, position, updatePositionAndMemory);
                break;
              case "ArrowRight":
                movePlayer(0, 1, position, updatePositionAndMemory);
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          };

          window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
          };
        }, );

        // Function to perform a random bot movement
        const randomMove = (botPosition, updatePositionAndMemoryBot) => {
          function getRandomInteger() {
            const randomNumber = Math.random();

            if (randomNumber < 1 / 3) {
              return 1;
            } else if (randomNumber < 2 / 3) {
              return -1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          }
          moveBot(
            getRandomInteger(),
            getRandomInteger(),
            botPosition,
            updatePositionAndMemoryBot
          );
        };

        // Perform random bot movements at a regular interval
        useEffect(() => {
          const randomMoveInterval = setInterval(() => {
            randomMove(botPosition, updatePositionAndMemoryBot);
          }, 500);

          return () => {
            clearInterval(randomMoveInterval);
          };
        }, );

        // ... (continued from previous comment)

        // Handle mouse button press on a cell
        const handleMouseDown = (cell) => {
          setMousePressed(true);

          const cellIndex = grid.findIndex((box) => box.key === cell.key);

          if (cellIndex !== -1) {
            const updatedCell = MakeCell("path", cell.y, cell.x);
            updateCellInGrid(cellIndex, updatedCell);
          }
        };

        // Handle mouse over a cell while mouse button is pressed
        const handleMouseOver = (key) => {
          if (mousePressed) {
            // Do something when mouse is moved over cells while pressed
          }
        };

        // State to track if the game is won
        const [gameIsWon, setGameIsWon] = useState(false);

        // Check if the player has reached the bot's position
        if (position.x === botPosition.x && position.y === botPosition.y) {
          setGameIsWon(true);
        }

        // Render the game components
        return (
          <div style={sectionStyle}>
            {gameIsWon ? (
              <h1>Winner</h1>
            ) : (
              <>
                <div style={gridStyles}>
                  {grid.map((cell) => (
                    <div
                      key={cell.key}
                      style={cell.style}
                      onMouseDown={() => handleMouseDown(cell)}
                      onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(cell)}
                    ></div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }

      export default BotTech;
```

The useEffect on line 230 will not update when the useEffect on line 181

Comment: It appears the setinterval timer is reset when a key is pressed. I need it to persist accros s rerenders